# Get specific element before THIS with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

This really sounds simple, so i'm not sure where am I stuck.
I have a form which I manually validate. after I check the radio buttons to be as required, I need to get the label above this element.
Here is the HTML. I cannot change the markup as this code is an inheritance and part of a bigger process.

So this is my HTML:

```
<label>Do you market on? : </label>
<li>
    <label>Plenty of Fish:</label>
    <span href="#" style="float:  left; margin-right: 10px;">
        <input type="radio" class="required" name="data[SignupAnswer][100][answer]" value="yes" />Yes
    </span>
    <span href="#" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;"> 
        <input type="radio" class="required" name="data[SignupAnswer][100][answer]" value="no" />No
    </span>
    <input type="hidden" name="data[SignupAnswer][100][signup_question_id]" value="100">
    <input type="hidden" name="data[SignupAnswer][100][class]" value="bool">
    <input type="hidden" name="data[SignupAnswer][100][required]" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="data[SignupAnswer][100][question]" value="Plenty of Fish">
</li>
```

I find the first radio, and then I need to find the label above it called "Plenty of Fish".

I tried with .prev(), and with .closest(), both with ('label'), but both didn't return an actual element but instead this object:

```
[prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1], context: <input>, selector: ".next(li)"]
```

Maybe someone can explain to me why I get this and not an element? and give me an idea how to get the required element?
Thanks!

Comment: can you please attach a jsFiddle?

Comment: Please add your jQuery code you tried with!!

Comment: Thanks guys, Someone answered before I even managed to set the jsFiddle :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`closest` selects the first closest parent element(*specified by the selector*), you can select the parent `li` element and then find the `label`:

```
$(this).closest('li').find('label')
```

Comment: Simple and working - seems I need to better use the console, as I tried the methods aboe :). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's to some family time. `.parents()` and `.children()`

```
$('input[value=yes]').parents('li').children('label')
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternate approach? `$('input[type="radio"]:first').parent().siblings('label')`